# How to break the item name and size in Django Cartridge cart page?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

When I use the code `{{ item.description }}` to print the **item name** on **cart.html** page in [django cartridge](https://github.com/stephenmcd/cartridge/), It prints the item name also size..**For example** aviesta is the item name  and size is 2.then it prints **(aviesta Size: 3)** ...**How can i break this name and size in 2 different parts..**
1. Item name
2. Item Size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it requires changes of the models, because when product is added to cart the name and options are saved to description:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    ...
    item.description = unicode(variation)
```

and

```
class ProductVariation(Priced):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        """
        Display the option names and values for the variation.
        """
        options = []
        for field in self.option_fields():
            if getattr(self, field.name) is not None:
                options.append("%s: %s" % (unicode(field.verbose_name),
                                           getattr(self, field.name)))
        return ("%s %s" % (unicode(self.product), ", ".join(options))).strip()
```

UPD:

You can add field to SelectedProduct class:

```
options = CharField(_("Options"), max_length=200)
```

Add method to ProductVariation class:

```
def options_text(self):
    options = []
    for field in self.option_fields():
        if getattr(self, field.name) is not None:
            options.append("%s: %s" % (unicode(field.verbose_name),
                                       getattr(self, field.name)))
    return ", ".join(options).strip() 

def __unicode__(self):
    """
    Display the option names and values for the variation.
    """        
    return ("%s %s" % (unicode(self.product), self.options_text())).strip()
```

Change add_item method in Cart class:

```
item.description = unicode(variation.product)
item.options = variation.options_text()
```